# How to create and configure Hadoop client script?

Tags: java, shell, hadoop, sqoop

There is a running Hadoop cluster.
And I have downloaded Hadoop distribution (in this case 0.20.205.0)

I need to create some shell script (bash/zsh/perl) that will be capable of calling Hadoop on that cluster. Ideally it should be able to be called from Sqoop script this way:

```
exec ${HADOOP_HOME}/bin/hadoop com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop "$@"
```

How can I call Hadoop and provide namenode/jobtracker URIs?
How do I provide extra libs with Sqoop and DB drivers?

Answer (score 1):

Should be simple enough using the hadoop generic options - Im assuming you've configured the contents of `${HADOOP_HOME}/conf` for your cluster (namely core-site.xml and mapred-site.xml)

```
exec ${HADOOP_HOME}/bin/hadoop com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop \
    -libjars myjar1.jar,myjar2,jar "$@"
```

Here you pass the jars to be placed on the classpath via the `-libjars` option.

If you have multiple clusters you want to target, then you'll just need to either create different conf folders for each cluster and set the `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` environment variable prior to calling the hadoop script, or you can use the `-Dkey=value` generic arguments to set the `fs.default.name` and `mapred.job.tracker` appropriately:

```
exec ${HADOOP_HOME}/bin/hadoop com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop \
    -libjars myjar1.jar,myjar2,jar \
    -Dfs.default.name=hdfs://namenode-servername:9000 \
    -Dmapred.job.jobtracker=jobtracker-servername:9001 \
    "$@"
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem actually was to run Sqoop.
So I solved it by simply supplying -fs and -jt parameters as first arguments to Sqoop command (e.g. sqoop-import)

```
sqoop-import \
    -fs $HADOOP_FILESYSTEM -jt $HADOOP_JOB_TRACKER  \
    --connect $DB_CONNECTION_STRING --username $DB_USER -P \
    --outdir /home/user/sqoop/generated_code \
    "$@" # <- other parameters
```